# Eigen::LLT< Eigen::MatrixXd > has incomplete type

Tags: c++, eigen3

Check out [this code](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html). Compiled on Ubuntu ...

```cpp
MatrixXd A(3,3);
A << 4,-1,2, -1,6,0, 2,0,5;
cout << "The matrix A is" << endl << A << endl;
LLT<MatrixXd> lltOfA(A); // compute the Cholesky decomposition of A
```

Here's a doctest case:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include <doctest/doctest.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>

TEST_CASE("llt")
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd A(3,3);
  A<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
  Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> lltof(A);
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
/src/test/test-proto.cc:40:38: error: variable ‘Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1> lltof’ has initializer but incomplete type
   Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> lltof(A);
```

What gives? This is reduced from my code to exactly represent the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops. Test case should be:

```
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include <doctest/doctest.h>
#include "proto.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense> //NOT Eigen/Core

TEST_CASE("llt")
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd A(3,3);
  A<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
  Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> lltof(A);
}
```

Note the change in `#include`.

Dumb mistake, but I'm leaving it up for my future self / google.

Comment: It would be sufficient to `#include <Eigen/Cholesky>`.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the example of this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments)

```
struct Y {};
template<const Y& b> struct Z {};
Y y;
Z<y> z;  // ok: no conversion
```

You better understand template none-type arguments .

Comment: This answer is not the most helpful. I did not define the type, I just instantiated it.